# Как при нажатии на кнопку скрыть другую кнопку а по нажатию на третью кнопку вернуть вторую кнопку?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $('.cd-see-all').click(function(){
  $(".gold_btn").fadeToggle(100);
});
```

Нашёл в интернете через jquery оно то скрывает но это не то что мне нужно, кто может подсказать )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не надо искать в интернете, как решать конкретную проблему. маловероятно, что вы найдете решение именно вашей проблемы. Вам следует найти, как с помощью jquery добавлять обработчик нажатия, и как скрывать/показывать элементы.

```js
$("#first").click(function(){
   $("#second").hide();
});

$("#third").click(function(){
   $("#second").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="first">1</button>
<button id="second">2</button>
<button id="third">3</button>
```

Решений у данной "проблемы" может быть множество.

Comment: Спасибо, лучший ))))

Comment: @ПашаИванов галку слева ткните, если помогло вам.